# How to Define a String Variable in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline Syntax

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I'm using scripted syntax in Jenkins and I need to send an email to a list of subscripers when the job fails.

I need this list to be defined in a variable not directly in the to: field.

But when I defined the global 'emails' variable and used it no emails were sent. How can I fix it?

```
 '''
    Pipeline build for ...
 '''

emails = 'email1@comp.com; email2@comp.com; email3@comp.com'

node('(ubuntu)'){

    stage ('Build App'){
        try{
                // code to execute
            }
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        } catch (err) {
            sh 'echo ${err}'
            emailext(
                subject: "",
                to: "${emails}",
                recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']],
                mimeType: 'text/html',
                body: content
            )
            sh 'exit 1'
        }
    }  
    
}
```

Comment: The mail list should be separated by a comma: `emails = 'email1@comp.com,email2@comp.com,email3@comp.com'` . In addition the syntax `to: emails,` is enough as `emails` it is a variable.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it did't work

Comment: Try to debug the plugin using [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71575305/13110835).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have this permission.